# Reading JSON with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am using JQuery to execute an operation within a web service. After writing data back to my databaes, the service returns a JSON response. My request looks like the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/services/myService.svc/PostMessage",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: '{"message":"testing","comments":"test"}',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
    if ((response.d != null) && (response.d.length > 0)) {
       // Parse the status code here
    }
    else { alert("error!"); }
  },
  error: function (req, msg, obj) {
    alert("error: " + req.responseText);
  }
});
```

When my response is returned, response.d contains the following:

[{"StatusCode":1}]

How do I parse out the value of the StatusCode?

Comment: Is `response.d` a string or an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an array containing an object with a `StatusCode` property.

You can write

```
alert(response.d[0].StatusCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function returns an array of `d` objects you can do this:

```
if ((response.d != null) && (response.d.length > 0)) {
       // Parse the status code here
       for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
          alert(response.d[i].StatusCode);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.